# Layer ATLConversationListViewController Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer

I am getting the following crash. I am using Layer messaging sdk and on it Atlas messenger sample. This issue is coming sometime when i am navigating from conversationListView to conversationView.  Is there any solution to it.

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba10b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b47c141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba14cf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b0163b6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010a03053d -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 15364
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010a039259 -[UICollectionView _endUpdatesWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 71
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a0395a0 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 437
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a0393c8 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:] + 91
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a03934a -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:] + 74
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a03929f -[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 53
    10  Atlas                               0x0000000104ed30ce -[ATLConversationViewController queryControllerDidChangeContent:] + 1134
    11  LayerKit                            0x0000000106bb2b0a __76-[LYRQueryController updateWithObjectIdentifiers:changedObjectsIdentifiers:]_block_invoke.239 + 74
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cde905c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cdcc0f8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 579
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cde905c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cdca40b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9d5909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b99bae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2164
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b99b016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010de41a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001096e50d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  SampleApp                            0x000000010439f797 main + 55
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001095c865d start + 1
)
```

Error Description:

```
[ATLConversationCollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.7.47/UICollectionView.m:5765
2017-06-23 11:33:27.473137+0530 SampleApp[1815:546610] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x19207afd8 0x190adc538 0x19207aeac 0x192b12710 0x198ab47cc 0x198ab865c 0x198ab893c 0x198ab879c 0x198ab8720 0x198380558 0x10099f14c 0x101eb12b4 0x105039a10 0x10504a5e4 0x105039a10 0x10503eb78 0x1920290c0 0x192026cdc 0x191f56d94 0x1939c0074 0x19820f130 0x10010b454 0x190f6559c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What description of the exception is printed into console when exception occurs?

Comment: @DisableR updated with error description

Comment: According to the exception, section is deleted from collection view, but dataSource of collection view still returns number of sections equal to 3. Check code of your collection view data source method `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView`, that after deletion of the section it has to return 2 instead of 3.